# Pick up directory with pyinstaller

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, pyinstaller

I have made a small programm with Python 3 and Qt-Designer using Pyqt5. 
the programm should open a pdf file which is located on a directory on my pc and another exe file, which is also on my pc. 
I'm using in the code:

```
os.startfile("D:\Python_files\MA\Programm\K_file\dist\K_D\K_D.exe")
os.startfile("D:\Python_files\MA\Programm\Help.pdf")
```

then I used pyinstaller to make it standalone app. The problem is that pyinstaller does not pick up those two file (`pdf` and `exe`). So when somebodyelse download the app on thier pc, it wont work because the pdf and the exe are missing. 
How to fix this? 
I'm using this command in `pyinstaller`

```
pyinstaller --onefile --icon="if_icon_64682.ico" --clean ProgV_1_6_Final.py
```